# Why enzyme.find('[htmlFor]') returns two elements instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, enzyme

I am testing below React stateless function which is basically three radio buttons:

```
export default function (props) {
    return (
        <ButtonToolbar className="float-right" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
          <ButtonGroup className="mr-3" data-toggle="buttons" aria-label="First group"
                onChange={props.handleLeaseOption}>
            <Label check htmlFor='option_active'
                    className={props.optionSelected === 'option_active' ?
                                classNameActive :
                                classNameInactive} >
              <Input type="radio"
                     name={name}
                     id='option_active'
                     value='option_active' /> Active
            </Label>
            <Label check htmlFor='option_inactive'
                    className={props.optionSelected === 'option_inactive' ?
                                classNameActive :
                                classNameInactive} >
              <Input type="radio"
                     name={name}
                     id='option_inactive'
                     value='option_inactive' /> Inactive
            </Label>
            <Label check htmlFor='option_all'
                    className={props.optionSelected === 'option_all' ?
                                classNameActive :
                                classNameInactive} >
              <Input type="radio"
                     name={name}
                     id='option_all'
                     value='option_all' /> All
            </Label>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>);
}
```

My test code is listed below - what I am trying to do is first set radio button to 'inactive' and when user clicks button 'active' then mock function is called.

```
test('Option Active', () => {
    const propsInactive = {"optionSelected": ConstVariables.optionInctive};
    const handleLeaseOption = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(LeaseOption(propsInactive));
    const inputActive = wrapper.find('[htmlFor="option_active"]');

    inputActive.simulate('click');
    expect(handleLeaseOption).toBeCalledWith(ConstVariables.optionActive);
});
```

With above code I got error:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 2 found instead.
```

Then I changed line selector to:

```
const inputActive = wrapper.find('[htmlFor="' + ConstVariables.optionActive + '"]').first();
```

This time I got error:

```
● Option Active

expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["option_active"]
But it was not called.
```

Can anybody help: 1. Why does my selector not working as expected? 2. Why my mock function is not called?